# TextMobject is not defined in Manim

Tags: python, manim

I tried adding text in Manim:

```
class FirstScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text=TextMobject("text")
        self.add(text)
```

but I get a `TextMobject is not defined` error. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite straightforward.

> "TextMobject" is not defined

This is a complaint that you `TextMobject` is not defined anywhere in your code, nor was it imported.

**EDIT**

After additional comments and information, the problem is that the `manim` library has updated and the current version has restructured its internal code organization. The guide that you linked to referenced an older version of `manim` where you would do `from manimlib.imports import` as if there was a separate `imports.py`.

The updated version however, would require you to do: `manimlib import *`. This is confirmed by checking the [official repository](https://github.com/3b1b/manim)'s guide. As well, [this is the updated](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/example_scenes.py) `examples_scene.py`, again from it's official repository.

```
from manimlib import *

class FirstScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        text=TextMobject("text")
        self.add(text)
```

If it complains about `Scene` not found, check that you have the latest version of the package installed (`git clone` again and re-install if you're using an outdated version). If you want to explicitly import it, the latest version points to `Scene` being at this location (https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/scene/scene.py), so your import path would be `manimlib.scene.scene`:

```
from manimlib.scene.scene import Scene
```

However, should you use `from manimlib import *` this would have been imported as well without you making explicit imports.

You can confirm this on the the package's `__init__.py`, [linked here](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/master/manimlib/__init__.py):

```
...
from manimlib.scene.scene import *
...
```

Either way, `TextMobject` should either be defined by you, or imported before you use it. I recommend you do an update, and then try again with the code above.

**EDIT 2**

In addition to the changes in how you import `Scene`, according to @giac's answer, `TexMobject` is renamed to `Tex` and `TextMobject` is renamed to `TexText`. I wouldn't count on it being still true or being the only changes so I recommend you check the [official repository](https://github.com/3b1b/manim)'s guide if you stumbled here trying to get an answer.

Comment: 'from manimlib.imports import *'
This is already imported in the file provided: "example_scenes.py". Still it is showing this error

Comment: @A.G. can you change that to `from manimlib import *` please? Can you also update your Question to include the complete code in `example_scenes.py` too so its easier to troubleshoot?

Comment: updated the description, and replaced this line as well, but then the error changed to Scene is not defined

Comment: I've edited my answer based on your latest input. I would recommend an update, or do a git clone and installation again. And then re-run your code with `from manimlib import *` instead or the older `from manimlib.imports import *`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, actually there was difference in class name. I was using TextMobject, but actually it was only text

Comment: I have the same issue, and I just installed the new version. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 10):

I found this just in case in the file `whatsnew.rst`

- `TexMobject` is renamed to `Tex`, `TextMobject` is renamed to `TexText`

Answer (score 3):

I too am pretty new to manim and ran into this exact same issue.  I found that you can replace `TextMobject` with `Tex` or `Text`.  I'm not sure exactly what the difference is, but they seem to be rendered with a slightly different font size.  I got an error trying to use `TexText`.